# how we can apply system rendered shadows to a view

Tags: android, drawable, material-design, xml-drawable

I am trying to implement shadows for my views. I have given a sample image which describe what I want, I need a google standard methods for implementing shadows,  I have tried with drawable images but as you know which is not standard method. [image: sample image]

Comment: what are "system rendered shadows" ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

Defining Shadows and Clipping Views

https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) as view container (which is in an official support library) and set properties:

```
    app:cardElevation="4dp" // shadow
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

where `app` namespace is:`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score 0):

In general, with **API21** you can use the [`view.setElevation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float)) method.
Better if you use the [`ViewCompat.setElevation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setElevation(android.view.View,%20float)) method.

Pay attention, it creates a shadow only in devices with API21+.
If you would like to create an elevation for other views for device with api<21, you have to use a custom drawable.

Currently the only standard view that supports elevation in all devices, is the `CardView`.
In this case you can use the [`setCardElevation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardElevation(float)) method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're thinking about older devices.

You can render shadows using RenderScript blurs and layer composition. This method is available since Android Froyo. It's pretty easy to create such shadows from scratch. You have to:

1. Draw a View as a black shape to an offscreen bitmap.
2. Blur that bitmap with ScriptIntrisincBlur
3. Draw that bitmap with alpha
4. Draw the original View on top of that shadow.

You have to specify a blur radius based on View's elevation. You may also offset the shadow a bit. For implementation details see:

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/shadow/ShadowGenerator.java

And

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/widget/LinearLayout.java#L128